# Get Django form in html from Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a django page with a fullcalendar in it. My usecase is that I want to be able to click on an event, that will open a pop up with to edit it (the event being a Django model). I think I cannot find the right keyword, because I cannot find any simple way to do this. Ideally, I would like a get method in my views file that will return only the form in html, and I will call it in a fullcalendar callback with an Ajax call, and then fill the pop-up body with it.

I am not a web expert, sorry if my vocabulary is not the right one :-).

Cheers,
Emmanuel

Comment: You can look up for "javascript modals" which is a kind of pop up dialog that shows up inside the page and can be programmed to load a specific page. Then, whenever the user clicks on the calendar widget, you show a new modal with the URL of your view that edits the event (something like this `/events/edit/?date=2014-09-27`).

Answer (score 0):

For Class-based view you can make like this:

1) Write AjaxMixin for return content of view via ajax(in JSON format) and add this for required View, which return form

```
class LazyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Promise):
            return force_text(obj)
        return obj

class AjaxViewMixin(View):
    """
    A mixin that can be used to render a JSON response for CBV.
    """
    payload = {}

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            html = render_to_string(self.template_name, context, context_instance=RequestContext(self.request))
            payload = {'success': True, 'html': html}
            payload.update(self.payload)
            response_kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(payload, cls=LazyEncoder), **response_kwargs)
        return super(AjaxViewMixin, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)
```

2) On html page like this:

```
$('open_form_button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post( '{% url 'view_which_return_form' %}' , function(data) {  //may use and get, no sense
        if (data.success) {
            $('#place_for_form').html($($.parseHTML(data.html,document,"true")).filter('*')) 
        }
    });
});
```

Sense of this- you return rendered form block in variable 'html' via Ajax and insert to required place.
Remember use

```
$($.parseHTML(data.html,document,"true")).filter('*')
```

for returned data, or you scripts in returned block not work correctly.